# XML attribute Parsing in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have an Xml.may i know how can i parse it.

i need to get all **OfficeName** in to an Dictionary/array from the below XML.

```
eg: 
Dictionary[key:tblOffice1]= "!-Everett Corporate Office" 
Dictionary[key:tblOffice2]= "!-Fullterton SCE Call Center" 
  etc..
```

.

the above thing is not a exact code.

please help me .

**my XML is**

```
    <DataTable xmlns="http://www.myoffice.com:1212/">
    <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="tblOffice" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="tblOffice">
            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="OfficeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<DocumentElement xmlns="">
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<OfficeName>!-Everett Corporate Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<OfficeName>!-Fullterton SCE Call Center</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<OfficeName>Columbus Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
<OfficeName>Edison Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
<OfficeName>Franklin Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
<OfficeName>Fullterton Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice7" msdata:rowOrder="6">
<OfficeName>Hatfield Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice8" msdata:rowOrder="7">
<OfficeName>Hayward Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice9" msdata:rowOrder="8">
<OfficeName>Las Vegas Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice10" msdata:rowOrder="9">
<OfficeName>Phoenix Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice11" msdata:rowOrder="10">
<OfficeName>Portland Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice12" msdata:rowOrder="11">
<OfficeName>Salt Lake Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice13" msdata:rowOrder="12">
<OfficeName>Snohomish Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
<tblOffice diffgr:id="tblOffice14" msdata:rowOrder="13">
<OfficeName>Spokane Office</OfficeName>
</tblOffice>
</DocumentElement>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

may i know , how can i do it.

i wrote the method

```
package com.timetracker.app;

import java.io.StringReader;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OfficeLocation extends ListActivity {

    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.myoffice.com:1212/getTTofficeNames";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME  = "getTTofficeNames";
    private static  String NAMESPACE = "http://www.markdevweb.com:8082/";
    private static  String URL = "http://www.markdevweb.com:8082/ttwss/ttadmin.asmx";
    ProgressDialog pbd;
    TextView tv;
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // for getting header in the list view
        //View offheader = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.offheader,null);

        //ListView listView = getListView();
        //listView.addHeaderView(offheader);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        System.out.println("the soap object request in officeloc = " +request);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        System.out.println("the soapserializationenvelope= "+envelope);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
          envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

       System.out.println("under the request  in officeloc");
       HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
       System.out.println("under the url  in officeloc");

       try{   
       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
       System.out.println("Under the soap action2  in officeloc");

     //SoapPrimitive resultString=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
      SoapObject resultString=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

    System.out.println("the result string displayed  ab in officeloc :" +resultString);

     XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
      factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
      XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

      xpp.setInput( new StringReader (resultString.toString() ) );
      int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
      while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

       if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
           System.out.println("Start document");

       } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

           System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
       } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
           System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
       } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
           System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
       }
       eventType = xpp.next();
      }
      System.out.println("End document");
      /*  try {
            XmlPullParser parsers=new org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser();
            parsers.setInput(new java.io.StringReader("<tblOffice><OfficeName>hayword</OfficeName></tblOffice>"));
            //parsers.nextTag();
            parsers.require(XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT, null, null);
            parsers.nextTag();
            parsers.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "tblOffice");
            parsers.nextTag();
            parsers.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "OfficeName");
            System.out.println("the elements"+ parsers.getText());
            parsers.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "OfficeName");
            parsers.nextTag();
            parsers.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "tblOffice");
            parsers.nextTag();
            parsers.require(XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/


        String result=resultString.toString();
           System.out.println("the new value  in officeloc "+result);


          String[] names = new String[] {result};
       this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.officelayout,R.id.label, names));
            }

       catch (Exception e) 
       {
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
       }



        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity

        //"Everett","Hayword","SaltLake","Vegas","Snohomish","Hatfield","Bothell"
        // Use your own layout and point the adapter to the UI elements which
        // contains the label
    //with larger size  this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));






    }       

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
            String keyword = o.toString();
            Toast.makeText(OfficeLocation.this, "you have pressed" + keyword+"the position is"+position+"the ID is"+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();


            if(position==0)
        {
            Context localContext1 = this.getApplicationContext();
              Intent localIntent1 = new Intent(localContext1, Everett.class);
            this.startActivity(localIntent1);
        }
                if(position==1)
                {
            Context localContext2 = this.getApplicationContext();
              Intent localIntent2 = new Intent(localContext2, Everett.class);
            this.startActivity(localIntent2);
                }
                if(position==2)
                {
            Context localContext3 = getApplicationContext();
              Intent localIntent3 = new Intent(localContext3, Everett.class);
              startActivity(localIntent3);
                }
                if(position==3)
                {
            Context localContext4 = getApplicationContext();
              Intent localIntent4 = new Intent(localContext4, Everett.class);
              startActivity(localIntent4);
                }
                if(position==4)
                {
            Context localContext5 = getApplicationContext();
              Intent localIntent5 = new Intent(localContext5, Everett.class);
              startActivity(localIntent5);
                }
                if(position==5)
                {
            Context localContext6 = getApplicationContext();
              Intent localIntent6 = new Intent(localContext6, Everett.class);
              startActivity(localIntent6);
                }
                if(position==6)
                {
            Context localContext7 = getApplicationContext();
              Intent localIntent7 = new Intent(localContext7, Everett.class);
              startActivity(localIntent7);
                }

                        }
}
```

However it like I am able to see get in to that method. of webservice.
and able to see the whole page   I am not able to filter it out by line by line.
 Its like a list of values.. but comming as the page as a whole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need here is XPath, should be something like that, not tested though:

```
    ArrayList<String> officeNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "//OfficeName";
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("offices.xml");


    NodeList nodeList;
    try {
        nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            officeNames.add(node.getNodeValue());
        }
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

More info about XPath in android: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Tutorial to get the full power of XPath:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html) a nice post that will help you understand how to parse XML in Android. Hope this helps.

Comment: i used this methods. but i didtn't get

Comment: @MithunMadhav, What do you mean under "exact way"? To parse your file for you? If you don't get anything you can always ask a specific question and we'll try to answer you, but noone will do your work for you.

Comment: @MithunMadhav, You've minused my answer cause I've refused to write your code for you?

Comment: accidentally my cursor touched there. sorry. i cant reset it to zero.

Comment: the window shows that "You last voted on this answer
11 mins ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited" what can i do?